# Как сохранить позицию в scrollview

Tags: java, android, scrollview

Есть такая разметка:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    <ImageView
        android:background="@drawable/food"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/potbacground" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/potehki1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:background="@drawable/food"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <ScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:id="@+id/a1scroll"
            >

            <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal" >
                <TextView

                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/eda"
                    android:id="@+id/eda_text"
                    android:textColor="@color/blue"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:textSize="40sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"

                    />
            </LinearLayout>

        </ScrollView>
    </LinearLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

имеется в ресурсах string текст,пример:
пролистал я до середины, вышел,захожу опятв приложение и загружается та позиция на которой я свернул приложение.
В сети нашел такой пример:

```
@Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        final ScrollView scrollView = (ScrollView) findViewById(R.id.a1scroll);
        final TextView textView = (TextView) scrollView.getChildAt(0);
        final int firstVisableLineOffset = textView.getLayout().getLineForVertical(scrollView.getScrollY());
        final int firstVisableCharacterOffset = textView.getLayout().getLineStart(firstVisableLineOffset);
        outState.putInt(ScrollViewContainerTextViewFirstVisibleCharacterOffset, firstVisableCharacterOffset);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
        final int firstVisableCharacterOffset = savedInstanceState.getInt(ScrollViewContainerTextViewFirstVisibleCharacterOffset);

        final ScrollView scrollView = (ScrollView) findViewById(R.id.a1scroll);
        scrollView.post(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                final TextView textView = (TextView) scrollView.getChildAt(0);
                final int firstVisableLineOffset = textView.getLayout().getLineForOffset(firstVisableCharacterOffset);
                final int pixelOffset = textView.getLayout().getLineTop(firstVisableLineOffset);
                scrollView.scrollTo(0, pixelOffset);
            }
        });
    }
```

но он как-то не понятен,особенно,что это:

```
ScrollViewContainerTextViewFirstVisibleCharacterOffset
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вот рабочий код для Вас - сохранение позиции при выходе из приложения. Использовал Вашу разметку, все работает как надо, однако код требует оптимизации

```
package firstknowok.us.ivanovsoftware.com.myapplicationtextview;

import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Parcelable;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.ScrollView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    TextView editText1;
    Parcelable state;
    int y=0;
    SharedPreferences sPref;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        editText1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.eda_text);

        String t = "";

        //Заполнил строками привет eda_text
        for(int i=0;i<100;i++){
            t=t+"Привет "+i+"\n";
        }
        editText1.setText(t);

        //Находим ранее сохраненное значение  после события onDestroy
        sPref = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
        final int y = sPref.getInt("YPOSITION", "");
        if (((ScrollView)findViewById(R.id.a1scroll)) != null){
            //Если было сохранение после onDestroy
            final ScrollView scrollView = (ScrollView) findViewById(R.id.a1scroll);
            scrollView.post(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                      scrollView.scrollTo(0, y); //Восстановим позицию scrollView
                }
            });

        }

        Log.i("ivansoft", "onCreate: "+savedText);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        y = ((ScrollView)findViewById(R.id.a1scroll)).getScrollY();
        sPref = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor ed = sPref.edit();
        ed.putInt("YPOSITION",y);  //Сохраним позицию при разрушении MainActivity
        ed.commit();
        Log.i("ivansoft", "onDestroy: "+y);
    }



}
```

Comment: А зачем putString() ?

Comment: Просто так, пусть человек подумает ;) ... Я же указал - код требует оптимизации.

Comment: Дело конечно ваше, но если вдруг человек не будет оптимизировать, а так и зарелизит, а потом кому то это сопровождать... Вот это savedText.length()!=0 например

Comment: Вы правы, мало ли что... Исправил описание ответа

Comment: Использовать `String` в качестве целочисленной переменной конечно никуда не годится. Так же `onDestroy()` не самое подходящее место для логики сохранения. Если приложение просто уйдет в фон без уничтожения или даже банально будет повернуто устройство, позиция не восстановится. Вы предлагаете для этих случаев другую логику писать? Я думаю проще использовать `onPause()`. Здесь у нас база рабочих решений, а не квесты - я написал, а ты переделай по подсказке. Использование `String` так нелепо - это, в первую очередь, ваша репутация. Что можно подумать о программисте, написавшем такое решение?

Comment: В onPause() будет другой код, по крайней мере надо будет вводить поправочный коэффициент для определения позиции scrollY т.к. при смене ориентации, будут другие координаты по осям X Y. Так например при вертикальном положении scrollY например будет 1920 , а при горизонтальном 1080  rjhdby уже обращал внимание на этот нюанс

Comment: @ivansoft 
final int y = sPref.getInt("YPOSITION", "/*а что тут нужно указывать???*/");

Answer (score 2):

Рабочее решение смотрите у ivansoft'а

Если же надо сохранять позицию при повороте экрана, то тут уже необходимо исскуственно привязываться к элементам внутри ScrollView. Вычислять, какой именно View находится в левом верхнем углу ScrollView и сохранять его тэг например. А после пересоздания скроллить до него же.

Comment: Почему при повороте нельзя использовать такое же решение по определению и восстановлению  позиции, как в ответе, на который вы ссылаетесь? Оно гораздо проще.. Фактически нужно только перенести логику сохранения из `onDestroy()`, в `onPause()`

Comment: Потому, что при повороте могут могут измениться геометрические размеры вьюх(было две строки текста, а стала одна например) и скролл по координатам приведет к совершенно другому контенту